# How to find AuthType of a user in a given domain

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am getting list of all users in a given domain (Active Directory) now i want to know that which user uses Kerberos and which user using NTLM.

how can i get a list of users which are using AuthType kerberos

Comment: Any user can use any authentication method the domain allows at any time. Users aren't restricted to one or the other. So one user could authenticate via Kerberos in one application, and NTLM in another.

Comment: as mentionned by G. Luci, authentication method is not a user property but a service. Although it's possible to disable NTLM by GPO (really not recommended), first of all you can implement Account Logon security auditing policy on DC's to collect Authentication method for NTLM (event 4624) and Kerberos services/ticket.

Comment: can i know this through code in c#